# Forvalues dropping leading 0's, how to fix?

Tags: stata

I am attempting to create a loop to save me having to type out the code many times. Essentially, I have 60 csv files that I need to alter and save. My code looks as follows:

```
forvalues i = 0203 0206 : 1112 {
    cd "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data\" 
    import delimited `i'.csv, varnames(1)
    gen time=`i'
    keep rssd9017 rssd9010 bhck4074 bhck4079 bhck4093 bhck2170 time
    save `i'.dta, replace
}
```

However, I am getting the error "203.csv" does not exist. It seems to be dropping the leading 0, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a *numlist*, but in this context `0203`, with nothing else said, just looks to Stata like a quirky but acceptable way to write `203`: hence your problem.

But do you really have a *numlist* that is `0203 0206 : 1112`?

Try it:

```
numlist "0203 0206 : 1112"
ret li
```

The list starts `203 206 209 212 215 218 221 224 227 230 233 236` ...

My wild guess is that you have files, one for each quarter over a period,  labelled `0203` for March 2002 through to `1112` for December 2011. In fact you do say that you have times, even though my guess implies 40 files, not 60. If so, that means you won't have a file that is labelled `0215`, so this is the wrong way to think in any case.

Here is a better approach. First take the `cd` out of the loop: you need only do that once!

```
cd "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data"
```

Now find the files that are `????.csv`. You need only install `fs` once.

```
ssc inst fs 
fs ????.csv 

foreach f in `r(files)' {

    import delimited `f', varnames(1)
    gen time = substr("`f'", 1, 4)  
    keep rssd9017 rssd9010 bhck4074 bhck4079 bhck4093 bhck2170 time
    save `time'.dta, replace
}
```

On my guess, you still need to fix the time to something civilised and you would be better off `append`ing the files, but one problem at a time.

Note that insisting on leading zeros, which you think is the problem here, but is probably a red herring, is written up [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0051).